# How to export dynamic nested collection data in cloud firestore using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image][image][image]How to export dynamic nested collection in cloud firestore using node js?

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var databaseURL = "databaseURL"; // Initiate databaseURL
var serviceAccount = require("../serviceaccount.json"); // Initiate serviceAccount
if (admin.apps.length) {
  admin.app();
} else {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: databaseURL
  })
}
var firestoredb = admin.firestore();
var CollectionName = request.body.CollectionName;
var SubCollectionName = request.body.SubCollectionName;
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  await firestoredb.collection(CollectionName).doc().collection(SubCollectionName).doc().get()
    .then(async snapshot => {
      var snap_size = snapshot.size;
      console.log("snap_size", snap_size)
      var arr_Collection_Details = [];
      snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
        var CollectionData = doc.data();
        arr_Collection_Details.push(CollectionData)
        fs.writeFile("filename.json", JSON.stringify(arr_Collection_Details), function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error:", err.message);
            res.json({
              returncode: 201,
              message: err.message
            })
          } else {
            console.log("Data Exported Sucessfully");
            res.json({
              returncode: 200,
              message: "Data Exported Sucessfully"
            })
          }
        });
      });
    })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.json({
      returncode: 201,
      message: err.message
    })
  })
});
module.exports = router;
```

I take subcollection data but i need nested collection data that nested collection name are dynamically.

how to write the query for nestedcollection

Comment: Hello, you need to give more details on how the dynamic aspect is implemented.

Comment: I add the db structure image in descending order  – Renaud Tarnec

Comment: Thanks. It is still unclear for me what you want to achieve. Can you explain it based on the screenshots? What is dynamic?

Comment: example there are 5 nested collection that 5 nested collection name are different then only i mention dynamic and i added my code also

Comment: To query documents in a collection, you need to know its full path. What do you expect from your code that doesn't work?

Comment: i neeed nested collection query and implement for this code

Comment: I don't think I can say more than "To query documents in a collection, you need to know its full path".

Comment: Is it possible to fetch all sub collections and its documents of a collection without knowing its internal sub collection names or document ids?

Comment: What you can do is to list the sub-collections of a document via a Cloud Function. This is explained in my article ["How to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document?"](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166), but I guess you know it since you wrote a response to this article. So, since you are using the Admin SDK, you can use the [listCollection](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask in the comments:

> Is it possible to fetch all sub collections and its documents of a
>   collection without knowing its internal sub collection names or
>   document ids?

While it is not possible, with the mobile and web client SDKs, to retrieve the list of subcollections of a document, it is possible with the Cloud Firestore server client libraries, and in particular with Firebase Admin Node.js SDK. This is explained in detail in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) *(Disclaimer, I'm the author)*

Since you use the Admin SDK, you can use this technique, as follows:

```
//Get the path of the parent pocument
const docPath = "col1/doc2/subcol4/doc7";  //For example

const collections = await admin.firestore().doc(docPath).listCollections();

const promises = [];

collections.forEach(collRef => {
    promises.push(collRef.get());
})
const querySnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promises);

querySnapshotsArray.forEach(querySnapshot => {
   querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
       console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
   });
 });
```

---

Note that there is a similar [`listCollections()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections) method to list all the root collections of your Firestore database.

Comment: I execute this program but comes an output on empty array

Comment: i added the image above

Comment: Please add the image to your original question. And also, more important, share your entire code. How do you `declare` docPath in particular.

Comment: I think that the easiest way to do this is using the Server side client library, or use a cloud function as @RenaudTarnec mention on his article   

https://gist.github.com/rtarnec/287c931487e5b56b655309c17ec0409f#file-listsubcollectionscloudfunctions-js

Comment: @VijayRahul I've seen your code. Plead **add it to your own question**, by editing it (using the edit link below your question) and not by editing my answer. Your code, based on the one in my answer, **does work**. I've successfully tested it. So you probably have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Hello @VijayRahul, I would kindly suggest you ask a new question, with as much detail as possible on your goal.In SO, it is better to keep the scope of a Question/Answer pair limited to a specific problem.